# Is there a faster way to get companions "to do something for me"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you get into the "I need you to do something for me" mode without going through the dialog tree with your companion?

Comment: I thought this was a SW:TOR question at first glance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you press and hold <kbd>X</kbd> (PS3) like you would to move an item around when your cursor is on your companion you immediately enter the "do something for me" mode.  I discovered this when trying to put a hat on an alchemy table that was being crowded by Lydia.

Comment: that's a nice find!  I wonder if the same functionality (E key) works on PC versions.

Comment: @yx Yes it does :)

Comment: Checked on Xbox 360 and worked (holding action button)